# vb.net WCF Iservice List(of String) and List( of mycustomclass) not working in webservice

Tags: arrays, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have the following vb.net web service code:

```
Public Interface IService
    <OperationContract()>
    Function SendEmail(CustomerNo As Int32, Password As String, FromEmail As String, _
        ToEmail As List(Of String), CCemail As List(Of String), Subject As String, _
        body As String, AttachmentList As List(Of DocumentDatabaseInfo)) As Boolean
End Interface
```

On the client side I have code like:

```
client.SendEmail(_Customer_CustomerNo, "duh", "Chris@3csol.net", myToList, myCcList, "testing", "testing", myAttachmentList))
```

- `myToList` is a `List(Of String)`
- `myAttachmentList` is a `List(Of my custom class)`

The `myToList`, and `myCCList` gives me an error:

> Value of type 'List(Of String)' cannot be converted to "String()'

The `myAttachmentList` gives me a similar error:

> Value of type 'List(of DocumentDatabaseInfo)' cannot be converted to 'DocumentDatabaseInfo()'

The `DocumentDatabaseInfo` class looks like:

```
Public Class DocumentDatabaseInfo
    Property CustomerNo As Int32
    Property DatabaseName As String
    Property DatabaseTableName As String
End Class
```

The class file is on both the client and the webservice server.

Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: ok thanks, I'm a newbie to the website.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692142/why-cant-value-of-type-listof-integer-be-converted-to-integer-when-sending-va?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array instead of List in WCF contracts.