# Why can't value of type List(Of Integer) be converted to Integer when sending value to WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services

Client code:

```
Public Sub sendEmpValue(name As String, value As List(Of Integer))
    Dim serviceObject As New Service.GetEmployeeClient
    serviceObject.DoWork(name, value)** getting error at the value**
End Sub
```

Service code:

```
Sub DoWork(name As String, value As List(Of Integer)) Implements IGetEmployee.DoWork
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: because list of integer is not integer. you have to convert it to the required datatype

Comment: Why can't I edit this. It's VB not C# someone please correct the tag.

Comment: somebody else must be modifying

Comment: thanks vivek,my question is that i mentioned list of integer in service but i can able to send only integer

Comment: `value.ToArray()`

Comment: It wants `Integer()` which is an array of integers. Call `value.ToArray()` and it should work.

Comment: I saw you marked my post as the answer, then unmarked it again. Is there a problem or was it just a misclick that you marked it in the first place?

Comment: Firsttime  I am using stack overflow I am checking your answer

Comment: Spoke too soon. See the update on my answer. -- If you find that it solves your problem you can mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark. And since you're new here I'd also advice you to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DoWork` method expects an `Integer()` which is *an array of integers*.

The [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class has got a function called [**`ToArray()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return the list as an array. Call that and it should work.

```
serviceObject.DoWork(name, value.ToArray())
```

**Read more about arrays on [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).**

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647027/3740093) when using WCF a `List(Of T)` is converted into an array on the clientside, which is why the `DoWork` method wants an array instead of a `List(Of Integer)` as you've specified. This behaviour can apparently be modified though.

Comment: @JohnNero : No problem! I'm glad to help!

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why this was fit for a downvote? My code might not address the issue that it expects an array instead of a `List(Of T)`, but I mentioned the other answer as an alternative - and I cannot do more because I am not familiar with WCF.